# Setting UILabel height in cellForRowAtIndexPath is not actually changing my label height when I run the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I am trying to set the height of my label inside of my UITableViewCell dynamically at runtime.  The height of the label is dependent on the content.  I have set in my custom UITableViewCell xib file that the UILabel should have 0 lines (no bounds).  Below is my code for CellForRowAtIndexPath.  I've looked around and tried a few things but nothing seems to work for me.

XYZPlayerTableViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int row = indexPath.row;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PlayerCell";
    XYZPlayerTableViewCell *cell = (XYZPlayerTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    XYZPlayer *player = [self.players objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *nameText = player.name;
    NSString *gameText = player.game;
    
    cell.nameLabel.text = nameText;
    cell.gameLabel.text = gameText;
    [cell.gameLabel sizeToFit];
    cell.gameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.ratingImageView.image = [self imageForRating:player.rating];

    CGSize boundingRect = CGSizeMake(cell.frame.size.width, 4000);
    CGRect expectedFrame = [cell.gameLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:boundingRect options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: cell.gameLabel.font}  context:nil];
    cell.gameLabel.frame = expectedFrame;
    
    NSLog(@"gameLabel = 0x%@  gameText = %@  gameLabelHeight = %.2f", cell.gameLabel, gameText, expectedFrame.size.height);
    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int row = indexPath.row;
    
    //set width depending on device orientation
    self.cellPrototype.frame = CGRectMake(self.cellPrototype.frame.origin.x, self.cellPrototype.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, self.cellPrototype.frame.size.height);
    
    // Get variables
    XYZPlayer *player = [self.players objectAtIndex:row];
    UILabel *nameLabel = self.cellPrototype.nameLabel;
    NSString *nameText = player.name;
    UILabel *gameLabel = self.cellPrototype.gameLabel;
    NSString *gameText = player.game;
    
    // Calculate height
    CGFloat nameLabelHeight =  [self sizeOfLabel:nameLabel withText:nameText].height;
    CGFloat gameLabelHeight = [self sizeOfLabel:gameLabel withText:gameText].height;
    CGFloat padding = nameLabel.frame.origin.y;
    CGFloat combinedHeight = padding + nameLabelHeight + padding/2 + gameLabelHeight + padding;

    return combinedHeight;
}
```

XYZPlayerTableViewCell.m

```
-(void)setGameLabelHeightForString:(NSString *)string
{
    self.gameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    gameLabel.text = string;
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(gameLabel.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX);
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [string sizeWithFont:self.gameLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping]; 
    CGRect newFrame = self.gameLabel.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    self.gameLabel.frame = newFrame;
}


-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    [self setGameLabelHeightForString:gameLabel.text];
}
```

The output at runtime is this:

### 2014-07-09 00:21:32.277 MyTestApp[24503:60b]

### gameLabel = 0x< UILabel: 0x8e42800; frame = (0 0; 321.946 81.124); text = 'Tic-Tac-Toe And another l...'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = < CALayer: 0x8e360d0>>

### gameText = Tic-Tac-Toe And another line and maybe some more because who know's how long this can go.  I think i need just a little bit more text to make this super obvious

### gameLabelHeight = 81.12

And this is what my app looks like.  The gray color shows the height of my label
[image: Screen shot]

Any one got any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you implement `– tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method? or set `rowHeight` property of UITableView .

Comment: You need to implement heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I've already implemented the heightForRowAtIndexPath method.  And you can see from the size of my UITableViewCell that it has already grown to an appropriate height

Comment: You should set the `numberOfLines` of `gameLabel` to zero.

Comment: I've done this in multiple places.  Nothing has worked.

The one thing I did get to work was when I implemented `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I changed the height by calling `setGameLabelHeightForString` which I implemented in my XYZTableCellView.  When I click on a cell, then the label changes and it fills in the TableCellView appropriately.  Any ideas why this needs to be done AFTER the table has finished loading???

Comment: Were you ever able to fix this? I'm having the exact same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to calculate height but it is not a recommended way

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     XYZPlayerTableViewCell *cell=(XYZPlayerTableViewCell *)[self tableView:tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     return CGRectGetMaxX(cell.gameLabel.frame)+5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use one more line of code

```
cell.gameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: I will try this soon.  But I'm curious, I have the numberOfLines property already set to 0 for that label in my xib file, why would it not be holding?

Answer (score 0):

To resize your Label according to your content you have to make sure of 2 things

Number of lines = 0
and call **sizeToFit** on your label.

Not sure if you are setting the lines. Try to set the lines inside delegate only, else it seems ok

```
 UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrmae:_textView.bounds];
 tempLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // Important to do 
 tempLabel.text = @"Your Text";
 [tempLabel sizeToFit]; // This will resize your Label and now you can use it's height to manage your textView.
```

This will resize the tempLabel according to it's text.
Try to set the numberOfLines inside the delegate only.
Also try to give the height of your cell according to your Labels by calculating them inside **heightForRowAtIndexPath** delegate

Comment: I am giving my cell the appropriate height in the heightForRowAtIndexPath method and that is working correctly.  I need to try setting the numberOfLines inside my delegate.  As of right now, I am just setting it in my xib file for that label, which I still don't understand why it is not holding

Comment: @Vince613 You should set the label's number of lines as zero as @superGokuN stated in his/her answer at the time of declaring the `gameLabel`. And, you are done with `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    float calulatedWidth = [self getWidthFromString:textTobePutInLabel];
    float calculatedHeight = [self getHeightFromString:textTobePutInLabel];
    cell.gameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(yourX,yourY,calulatedWidth,calculatedHeight)
    cell.gameLabel.text = gameText;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   float height = [self getHeightFromString:textTobePutInLabel];
   return height;
}

- (float)getWidthFromString:(NSString *)strName{

    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(9999, 9999);

    CGSize size = [strName boundingRectWithSize:maximumSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:MAVEN_PRO size:13.0f]} context:nil].size;

    return size.width;
}

- (float)getHeightFromString:(NSString *)strName{

    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(9999, 9999);

    CGSize size = [strName boundingRectWithSize:maximumSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:MAVEN_PRO size:13.0f]} context:nil].size;

    return size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things

1. Override `heightForRowAtIndexPath` of `UITableViewDelegate` to return height of the cell dynamically based on the text.
2. Override `layoutSubviews` of `UITableViewCell` (XYZPlayerTableViewCell) to recalculate and set the frame for label.

YOu can use

```
CGSize labelSize = [self.gameLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11]
                                             constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, NOTIFICATION_DESC_MAX_HEIGHT + 5)
                                                 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

for calculating best fitted height if you are setting String to label or

```
CGRect rect = [self.gameLabel.attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300, NOTIFICATION_DESC_MAX_HEIGHT + 5)
                                                                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                                                                    context:nil];
```

if you are using AttributedString for your label

-- Vishal

Comment: I tried this and still it did not help.  I added the code I used in the latest edit.

Comment: did you added new calculated height to Label Frame ? did you checked if the function is returning right height ?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code and I noticed one problem with the statement `[gameLabel sizeToFit];` to be placed after setting the frame for the label.

i.e., after these lines

```
CGSize boundingRect = CGSizeMake(cell.frame.size.width, 4000);
CGRect expectedFrame = [cell.gameLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:boundingRect options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: cell.gameLabel.font}  context:nil];
cell.gameLabel.frame = expectedFrame;
```

Comment: I tried removing that line and had the same result.  As I said in a comment above, it seems like anything I do inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` fails.  I removed the label from my xib and created a label from scratch and added it to the subview, that is working now.  It seems wrong though that I couldn't use the label that was already in my xib.